# Korean manga about second daughter of noble was forgotten after first daughter was found

Tags: story-identification, manga, medieval

From what I remembered of the story it follows the second daughter of a noble.

The first daughter was kidnapped as a baby so the family had a second daughter.  After 16-18 years the first daughter was found again, leading the parents to forget about their second daughter when it was convenient.

At some point they wanted to have the second daughter break off her engagement to another noble house so they could have the first daughter marry him instead. Neither the first or second daughter wanted this to happen but the parents don’t care.

I believe the main character had either brown or black hair

I first saw this web manwa around 6-10 months ago and I forgot to mark down the series when I had the chance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Was there anything science-fictional or fantastical about this manhwa? Was it an isekai, was there magic or spells?

Comment: I do not think it was an isekai and while I do think there were hints of magic I don’t think it was all that important especially in the earlier chapters that I read

Comment: I found it. I got luck while searching YouTube and found a short that lead me to it.  The title is “I hated it even more”

Comment: @qazmlpok - I've had a look through that manga. It's definitely on-topic. There are spells and charms, gods and dragons and all sorts of fantasy tropes

Comment: Alternatively it could be "Real daughter is back" which is indeed fantasy.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the OP, this is *[I hated it even more](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/no-more-of-this)*. It will be licensed by Manta as *[The Last Straw](https://manta.net/en/series/the-last-straw?seriesId=2121)*

> You can have everything else, but not him!
>
> When Anita's **long-lost older sister Arabella finally turns up** after 19 years, their parents are overjoyed and begin to shower her with the love and attention Anita never received. But when they try to take away her best friend and fiancé, Axion, Anita finally puts her foot down. She's had enough.

The protagonist's older sister was kidnapped as a baby, leading to the parent having another child solely to continue the bloodline - this is the protagonist. Her parents never loved her, and continue to pine over their missing baby daughter.

Eventually the kidnapped daughter does return, and her parents shower her with affection, gifts, and take everything possible from their other daughter. This includes attempting to annul the protagonist's engagement with  her fiance.

[image]

The story is on-topic; the early chapters are mundane, but later on there are explicit references to divine power and spirits.

[image]

Comment: What are these, [thumbnails for ants](https://media.tenor.com/e_vPwqBG5WUAAAAC/tiny-text.gif)?

Comment: They can be clicked to expanded. Longstrip webtoons just really don't screenshot well.

Comment: Personally, I'd just grab the relevant panels and post those screenshots instead of the entire strip